# Sum of elements in a C array

Tags: c, arrays

I have just started learning C today, not very used to the syntax since previously I had only been using Python. I have this assignment.

Write a function that returns the sum of first n numbers in num_array of size 10. If n is an invalid number (i.e. not within 0 to 10 inclusive), return the value -1 instead to indicate an error.

Here's my attempt, which is not working for some reason. I don't have a proper IDE to check my code as I do not know any free newbie friendly IDEs for beginners. Can anyone tell me what went wrong here?

```
int num_array[10] = {3, 4, 6, 1, 0, 9, 8, 6, 2, 5};

int nth_sum_of_num_array(int n) {
    if !(0 <= n <= 10) {
        return -1;
    }
    else {     
        int result = 0; 
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            result += num_array[i];
        }
        return result;
        }

}
```

I would also appreciate suggestions on a free and newbie friendly C IDE with compilers.

Comment: The other problem is already solved. I would also appreciate suggestions on a free and newbie friendly C IDE with compilers. `vim & gcc`. I am not joking, when learning new language do not use IDEs. Learn the language and than use IDE.

Comment: @GRC I dont get the difference between learning a language and use IDE

Comment: I don't get it @GRC, why are you telling him not to use an IDE, but then suggesting the best IDE there is out there ? Anyway, yeah, vim & gcc are basically the best options you can get.

Comment: If you want to learn C. Just pick your favorite editor, `vim` is a text oriented workhorse, but if you are used to the windows type editors, then [Geany](http://www.geany.org/) is quite nice. The open a terminal and compile and run your code from there. You can't effectively use an IDE, until you know how to compile, what compiler options to use, etc.. Until you know that, you can't tell an IDE what to do to begin with.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin do you then know how to learn the syntax of C properly? I think I'm too spoonfed with the convenience of Python, and it takes a lot of trial and error to figure out what works and what doesn't

Comment: Unless you were specificly told to access the array as a global variable a better function would accept the array as one of its parameters.

Comment: There is no tricks to it. Every C-library function has a `man page`, e.g. [printf(3) - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html), each time you use a function, check the man page. This site is also very useful, and a good book helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change the condition:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int num_array[10] = {3, 4, 6, 1, 0, 9, 8, 6, 2, 5};

int nth_sum_of_num_array(int n) {
    if (n > 9|| n < 0) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            result += num_array[i];
        }
        return result;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    printf("The result is %d", nth_sum_of_num_array(6));
}
```

BTW, for a good C IDE, try [[image]clion](/questions/tagged/clion).

Comment: I'm not very comfortable seeing the indentation of `else` and `if` not being aligned, but the code still somewhat works. How do you do it?

Comment: Unlike python, C does not care about indentation.

Answer (score 2):

This may work in python:

```
if !(0<=n<=10)
```

But not in C. This is how you do it in C:

```
if (n <= 0 || n >= 10) {
```

Each condition has to be separated by a logical operator.

Comment: Check your edge-cases.